# Storing user values in a Python list using a for loop

Tags: python

This is my Code for Asking user to input the number of cities and should allow only that number of cities to enter
Requirement is to use For Loop

```
global number_of_cities
global city
global li
global container
li = []
number_of_cities = int(raw_input("Enter Number of Cities -->"))
for city in range(number_of_cities):
    city = (raw_input("Enter City Name -->"))
    li = city
    print li[]
```

Comment: it prints only 2nd city name

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in your code that is not meeting your expectations? What error messages are you receiving, if any?

Comment: when i enter number of cities = 2 i am entering name of two cities after that it is holding only last name that i entered

Comment: `li[]` is a SyntaxError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a list of the cities in `li` you can do the following:

```
li = []
number_of_cities = int(raw_input("Enter Number of Cities -->"))
for city in range(number_of_cities):
    li.append(raw_input("Enter City Name -->"))
print(li)
```

No need for the `global` in front of the variables and no need to define the other variables at the beginning, only the empty list.

Actually this is a nice example for learning list comprehension, e.g.

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter Number of Cities: "))
li = [raw_input('City Name: ') for city in range(n)]
print(li)
```

This gives:

```
>>> n = int(raw_input("Enter Number of Cities: "))
Enter Number of Cities: 4
>>> li = [raw_input('City Name: ') for city in range(n)]
City Name: London
City Name: Paris
City Name: Dubai
City Name: Sidney
>>> print(li)
['London', 'Paris', 'Dubai', 'Sidney']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
li = city
```

Use

```
li.append(city)
```

Hope thi helps.